# Simple For loop and if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, incremental-build

What I am trying to do is limit the withdrawal amount by $20 increments up to $500.  I know I am missing some simple element in here to do this.  My code worked until I tried to do the increments of 20.

```
double AccountBalance = 1500;
double WithdrawalAmount;
WithdrawalAmount = double.Parse(textInput.Text);
Double MaxWithdrawalAmount = 0;
for (MaxWithdrawalAmount = 0; MaxWithdrawalAmount <= 500; MaxWithdrawalAmount += 20)
{ 
    if (WithdrawalAmount == MaxWithdrawalAmount)
    {
        double Total = (AccountBalance - WithdrawalAmount);
        textTotal.Text = ("Total amount" + Convert.ToString(Total));
    }
    else
    {
        textError.Text = ("Only Increments of $20 allowed for withdraw up to $100");
        textTotal.Text = ("" + AccountBalance);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Can you privide some example output?

Comment: And what isn't working now?

Comment: You seem to be missing scope brackets after your for statement.

Comment: It will just show the 1500 and go to the Else statement

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear on the output

Comment: @woogy - the for loop syntax is valid; probably less than ideal for maintainability, valid nonetheless.

Comment: @woogy nope, the whole if/else is considered a single instruction block so there is no need of brackets. Not that I like it though.

Comment: use decimal instead double (this not core of Your problem, but good pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle your loop in a different way

```
bool ok = false;
for (MaxWithdrawalAmount = 0; MaxWithdrawalAmount <= 500; MaxWithdrawalAmount += 20)
{
    if (WithdrawalAmount == MaxWithdrawalAmount)
    {
        double Total = (AccountBalance - WithdrawalAmount);
        textTotal.Text = "Total amount" + Convert.ToString(Total);
        ok = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!ok)
{
    textError.Text = ("Only Increments of $20 allowed for withdraw up to $100");
    textTotal.Text = ("" + AccountBalance);
}
```

I have moved the error message outside the loop. If, inside the loop I find the correct value for withdrawal then I stop the loop and set a flag to avoid the final error message

Side note, if you don't need double values the whole code could be reduced to a few lines using the [remainder operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) . For example

```
int WithdrawalAmount = 120;
if ((WithdrawalAmount % 20) == 0)
   ... good ...
else
   ... bad ...
```

Comment: Uhm, I would like to know what is the error, thanks.